# How to add a property to an object at a specific index of an array in typescript (Angular)?

Tags: angular, typescript

```
emailData.contractors = [
                    0: {
                         id: 1,
                         email: asd@asd
                       }
                    1: {
                         id: 1,
                         email: asd@asd
                       }
                  ]
```

```
emailSub(event, data) {
    const trigger = $(event.target);
    this.emailData.contractors.forEach((v, i) => {
      if (v.id == data.id) {
        this.emailData.contractors[0]['subject'] = trigger.val();
      }
    });
  }
```

*Expected Output*

```
                    0: {
                         id: 1,
                         email: asd@asd
                         subject: 'sdf'
                       }
                    1: {
                         id: 1,
                         email: asd@asd`enter code here`
                       }
                  ]
```

**How can i achive this in angular 8. the function above is not working on a keyup of an input from which i get the data**

Comment: `[
                    0: {` is not valid syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Object.assign` to add an property.

Try like this:

```
emailSub(event, data) {
   const trigger = $(event.target);
   let item = this.emailData.contractors.find(x => x.id == data.id);
   Object.assign(item, {'subject':trigger.val()})
}
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s5gho2?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Answer (score 0):

change your data to

```
emailData.contractors = [
                {
                     id: 1,
                     email: "asd@asd"
                },
                {
                     id: 2,
                     email: "asd@asd"
                }
              ]
```

Or

```
emailData.contractors = {
                0: {
                     id: 1,
                     email: "asd@asd"
                },
                1: {
                     id: 2,
                     email: "asd@asd"
                }
              }
```

Comment: is my function should work,,,, those data is for example ... i got the emailData.contractors from an api  like this  
``` data: [,…]
0: {company: "ABC Maintenance", address: "17/52 Holker Street", preferred: 0, phone: "(03) 9508 5588 ",…}
1: {company: "AZ Electrician", address: 13, preferred: 0, phone: "(02) 9875 0000 ", fax: "9522 1111",…}
2: {company: "AZ Plumbing", address: "Sydney", preferred: 0, phone: "(02) 9443 8899 ", fax: "9887 6677",…}
```